# Slim 3: How to create cache pages?

Tags: php, caching, slim-3

I know how to create a cache page with plain php, for instance,

```
// @ref: http://wesbos.com/simple-php-page-caching-technique/
//
// define the path and name of cached file
$cachefile = 'cache/'.date('M-d-Y').'.php';

// define how long we want to keep the file in seconds. I set mine to 1 hour.
$cachetime = 3600;

// Check if the cached file is still fresh. If it is, serve it up and exit.
if (file_exists($cachefile) && time() - $cachetime < filemtime($cachefile)) {
    include($cachefile);
    echo '<!-- cached page - '.date('l jS \of F Y h:i:s A', filemtime($cachefile)) . ' -->';
    exit;
}

// if there is either no file OR the file to too old, render the page and capture the HTML.
ob_start();
?>
    <html>
        output all your html here.
    </html>
<?php

// We're done! Save the cached content to a file
$fp = fopen($cachefile, 'w');
fwrite($fp, ob_get_contents());
fclose($fp);

// finally send browser output
ob_end_flush();
```

But how can I do it in Slim 3 or other micro frameworks?

```
use Slim\Http\Request;
use Slim\Http\Response;

require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App();

// Routes:
$app->get('/', function (Request $request, Response $response, array $args) {
    $response->getBody()->write('Hello, World!');

    return $response;
});

$app->run();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the same, Slim-3 framework, but I'm using the caching as a middleware:

```
<?php
    $app->add(
        new \App\Middleware\HttpCache\Cache($container)
    );
```

inside that Class, you can add your methods:

```
<?php

    namespace App\Middleware\HttpCache;
    use App\Middleware\Middleware;

    class Cache extends Middleware {
        *// your methods go here*
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I like the idea of using the caching as a middleware!